# values are not saving after refreshing the page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, database, controllers, multi-vendor

we are using marketplace multivendor site, so we gave an option for seller to update the product attributes from frontend.
 now if we update attribute values from backend  , its working fine in frontend. but **if we try saving in frontend,its not saving in backend**.

In frontend, its saving, but after refreshing the page, it show old values..

we are using following code to save values in database :

**Phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('mp_local_shipping_charge');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "local[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**JS**

```
function hideResetLocal(product_id,localold) { 

var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuelocal).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currlocal).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldLocal(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valuelocal).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }




function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
 public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
 //   Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); 

     Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
     $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())->setMpLocalShippingCharge($upd_local)->save();

    $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
    $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

    try{
    $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
     Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())->setMpLocalShippingCharge($upd_local)->save();


    echo $name = $product->getName();

    $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

    }    

  }
```

Comment: what is type of this attribute?

Comment: it is  at textfield

Comment: try this `$product->setData('local',$upd_local);`

Comment: i added your code below this line :  $product->setLocal($upd_local); , but it didt worked

Comment: replace with this line ...

Comment: stll not saving in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
 $product->setData('mp_local_shipping_charge', $upd_local)
            ->getResource()
            ->saveAttribute($product, 'local');

    $product->save();
```

or try that

```
try{
    $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
     Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())->setMpLocalShippingCharge($upd_local)->save();


    echo $name = $product->getName();

    $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

    }
```

Comment: sorry, not saving, may i reindex once more ?

Comment: i reindexed, but still same issue

Comment: remove this code`Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); ` add new code try that..

Comment: i tried but it didt worked....

Comment: have you tried second suggestion?

Comment: yes, i am getting this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: i fixed that syntax eror, now also not saving

Comment: i just test second code it  is working fine.. change the attribute then check value is changing?

Comment: i will check one more time

Comment: i updated the question with code you gave me